# What time units are provided by BTrace when using @Duration annotation? Millis, micros or maybe nanos? Cannot find it in the documentation

Tags: java, profiling, btrace

Look at method 'methodExit'. What units of time are held in parameter "@Duration long time"?

```
package com.sun.btrace.samples;

import com.sun.btrace.Profiler;
import com.sun.btrace.annotations.*;
import static com.sun.btrace.BTraceUtils.*;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.AWTEvent;
import java.awt.event.FocusEvent;

@BTrace
public class AllMethods {

    @OnMethod(
        clazz="java.awt.EventQueue",
        method="dispatchEvent",
        location=@Location(Kind.RETURN))
    public static void methodExit(@Duration long time, @ProbeMethodName String pmn) {
        println(pmn + " " + (time / 1000000));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The duration is measured in nanoseconds.

The javadoc is missing this information - I have filed an [issue](https://github.com/btraceio/btrace/issues/265) for that. If you want to dig in the sources [this place](https://github.com/btraceio/btrace/blob/master/src/share/classes/com/sun/btrace/util/templates/impl/MethodTrackingExpander.java#L466) is a good start.

Comment: It would be great if you could add a source to prove your answer is right so that others can learn more about this if they want. A short answer like this might be mistaken as not being an answer at all (although it does answer the question in this case).

Comment: @JB- Could you provide any reference to documentation or source code?